# LibGDX Textfield has no pointer cursor or blinking on hover / focus

Tags: java, libgdx

```
    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    TextField.TextFieldStyle style = new TextField.TextFieldStyle();
    style.font = font;
    style.fontColor = Color.BLACK;
    style.cursor =
    style.selection = new Image(new Texture("core/assets/skin/textfield-big.png")).getDrawable();
    style.background = new Image(new Texture("core/assets/skin/textfield-big.png")).getDrawable();
    text = new TextField("Name", style);
    text.setWidth(500);
    text.setHeight(37);
    text.setPosition(50, 50);
    stage.addActor(text);
```

When I draw my stage, I can see my `textfield`, but when I hover it, my cursor doesn't change, and when I focus I can't see that blinking " | " at all, like normal textfields have.

What did I do wrong? Is it because `style.cursor` is null? If yes, how can I set it to the default cursor that libgdx uses?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue, but for future scrollers: A lot of people suggest that you load up a seperate drawable, but to me that feels like overkill for the one character. Instead, what I do (as of today) is use a Pixmap to get a black rectangle the size of the '|' character, then feed that in as the drawable for the cursor image.

Similar logic also works for the selection variable, which you may be interested in changing as well.

```
Label oneCharSizeCalibrationThrowAway = new Label("|", yourLabelStyle);
Pixmap cursorColor = new Pixmap((int) oneCharSizeCalibrationThrowAway.getWidth(),
            (int) largeSizeCalibrationThrowAway.getHeight(),
            Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
cursorColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
cursorColor.fill();

yourTextFieldStyle.cursor = new Image(new Texture(cursorColor)).getDrawable();
```

Comment: You saved my day